# Is it possible to add data in a field that already has existing data stored?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert, alter

Is it possible to add data in a field compared to updating the entire field?

For example, in a table

```
ID FName Interests 
1  Geno  Math
```

Is it possible for me to write a SQL statement of instead updating interests where id = and retyping Maths, Science. Instead i can just insert the value Science and it inserts it into the interests field after the data currently stored?

```
ID FName   Interests
1   Geno   Math, Science
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this:**

```
Update [YourTable]
SET Interests= CONCAT(Interests,',Science')
WHERE Id=[someid]
```

You can update by using `CONCAT()` for appending `,science` with the existing column value.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but do not do it!  You have two different entities in your database, "users" (of some sort) and "interests".

The proper way to store this data is using a table with one row per user and interest:

```
create table UserInterests (
    UserInterestId int auto_increment primary key,
    UserId int not null,
    Interest varchar(255),
    constraint fk_UserInterests_UserId foreign key (UserId) references ?(id)
);
```

Then you can assign a new interest very easily:

```
insert into UserInterests
    values ($userId, $interest);
```

(Note:  You should use parameters for such queries and not just put the values into the query string.)

Why is this the "right" way?  Consider the following:

- SQL columns (with the exception of special types such as JSON and XML) are designed to store single values.
- SQL has a great data structure for storing lists; it is called a *table*.
- MySQL does not have particularly powerful string functions.
- Queries on interests cannot take advantage of interests.
- Simple things like getting the list of interests are really, really difficult with the values munged together in a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONCAT()` function like below but at the end you will have to perform an `UPDATE` operation.

```
update tbl1
set Interests = concat(Interests,', Science')
where id =1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to retype, only concatenate -

```
update t  
set col=concat_ws(',',col,'new att')  
where ...
```

But you don't really want to do this.
Bad design.